# Access to the path is denied even when i run the application as administrator?

Tags: c#, .net

in the code below I'm trying to extract a dll file from the running application and save it to System32 directory :

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Text;
  using System.IO;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
  using System.Security.Cryptography;
  using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace ConsoleApplication1
 {
class Program
{

    public static void ExtractSaveResource(String filename, String location)
    {
        //  Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        // Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Installer.Properties.mydll.dll"); // or whatever 
        // string my_namespace = a.GetName().Name.ToString();
        Stream resFilestream = a.GetManifestResourceStream(filename);
        if (resFilestream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(resFilestream);
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create); // say 
                BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
                byte[] ba = new byte[resFilestream.Length];
                resFilestream.Read(ba, 0, ba.Length);
                bw.Write(ba);
                br.Close();
                bw.Close();
                resFilestream.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception E) { MessageBox.Show(E.Message); }
        }
        // this.Close(); 

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string systemDir = Environment.SystemDirectory;
        ExtractSaveResource("MySql.Data.dll",systemDir);

    }
}
}
```

Exception Message :

```
Access to the path C:\Windows\System32 is denied
```

I tried to copy the file into other directory like D:\ or X:\ but i always get this exception message
How could this be solved ?

Comment: You're writing to `C:\Windows\System32` because you use `Environment.SystemDirectory` explicitly; if you were writing to `D:\` I don't think you'd see this problem.  Are you running elevated?  Remember that in Windows there is difference between an "Administrator user" and "Running as adminstrator."

Answer (score 1):

You're using `Environment.SystemDirectory`, which is why it's trying to save out there.  However, even if you're running under the Administrator user, certain system folders are protected.  The system32 folder is one of them.  You would have to turn off UAC temporarily to save something there programmatically, which is not really a good thing to do.

I would very strongly recommend that you find a different/better way to do this.

Comment: I tried to save the file into another non-protected directory like D:\\ but i get an access denied error ??

Comment: @ShikataGaNai Try `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);`.  This will save to the current user's My Documents folder, where you're guaranteed to have write access.  if you still get an access denied error there you're dealing with something other than the obvious.

Comment: The access to MyDocuments is also denied ? How could this be !

Comment: @ShikataGaNai Try changing your stream invocation to `new FileStream(location, FileMode.Create, FileIOPermissionAccess.Write);`.  I have a sneaking suspicion you never requested write permissions.  Alternatively, or additionally, check what `FileStream.CanWrite` equals.